# Why are do the buttons in my radio groups all behave like they're in one group?

Tags: delphi, radio-button

In Delphi 2010, I have placed 2 radio groups onto a form then added 2 buttons to each group. so there are 4 buttons in total.

The problem is that the buttons' `Checked` properties behave as if all 4 buttons are in the same radio group. I.e., only 1 of the 4 buttons can be checked at any time. This is true both at design and run time.

```
  object RadioGroup1: TRadioGroup
    Left = 14
    Top = 314
    Width = 177
    Height = 35
    Caption = 'Series 2 Axis'
    TabOrder = 14
  end
  object RButtonLeftAxis: TRadioButton
    Left = 91
    Top = 326
    Width = 41
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'Left'
    TabOrder = 12
    OnClick = RButtonLeftAxisClick
  end
  object RButtonRightAxis: TRadioButton
    Left = 138
    Top = 326
    Width = 45
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'Right'
    Checked = True
    TabOrder = 13
    TabStop = True
    OnClick = RButtonRightAxisClick
  end
```

blah blah more objects

```
  object RadioGroup2: TRadioGroup
    Left = 8
    Top = 146
    Width = 113
    Height = 69
    Caption = 'Output Type'
    TabOrder = 33
  end
  object RadBtnkWh: TRadioButton
    Left = 20
    Top = 165
    Width = 65
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'kWh'
    TabOrder = 34
    OnClick = RadBtnkWhClick
  end
  object RadBtnLossFact: TRadioButton
    Left = 20
    Top = 188
    Width = 81
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'Loss Factors'
    TabOrder = 35
    OnClick = RadBtnLossFactClick
  end
```

How do I unlink these 2 groups?

Comment: You should put radiobuttons inside a Group Box, not a RadioGroup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have added radio buttons to TRadioGroup manually. Don't do that. Just click on the proerty Items of the radio group and write the strings (name of various radio buttons) there. And you get one radio group ready !

[image]

Comment: It appears he's put them beside, not quite inside (in DFM terms, not visual terms), the radio groups, which he is using like they were bevels. +1 for helpy-helpy answer.

Answer (score 3):

You've got crossed up somewhere

You add buttons to a radio group by setting the [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup.Items) property.

You have two TRadioGroups and four radio buttons, and they all have the same parent, so therefore they are in one group.

So get rid of the buttons and use the radio groups properly.

Or get rid of the radio groups and put them in another container.

Answer (score 2):

Your `TRadioButton` controls act as if they are in a single group because they **ARE** in a single group, as they have the same `Parent` - which is the `TRadioGroup.Parent`, **NOT** the `TRadioGroup` controls themselves.  You did not actually place the buttons **IN** the groups at all.  The DFM you showed proves that.  All you did was place the buttons **ON TOP OF** the groups instead of **INSIDE** the groups.

The `TRadioGroup.ControlStyle` property does not have the `csAcceptsControls` flag enabled, so you cannot drop `TRadioButton` controls onto a `TRadioGroup` at design-time.  That is why `TRadioGroup` is not becoming the button's `Parent`, but instead the `TRadioGroup.Parent` is becoming the button's `Parent`.  To put buttons **INSIDE** the `TRadioGroup`, you need to use the `TRadioGroup.Items` property instead.  However, that does not offer you any control over the positioning of the buttons.  If you need that, you have to use another container instead, such as a `TPanel` or `TGroupBox`, that you can drop `TRadioButton` controls onto.